# Interval of continuity over a jump

Tags: calculus, continuity

I thought I had this figured out but recently I was told some of what I think is conflicting information. I just want to clarify for my own peace of mind.

Consider the piecewise function:

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      x&x<2\\
      x+2&x\geq2 \\
   \end{cases}$$

If we were told to find the intervals *on* which $f$ is continuous, the answer should be $(-\infty, 2)\cup[2,\infty)$.

If we were told to find the intervals *over* which $f$ is continuous, then the answer should be $(-\infty, 2)\cup(2,\infty)$.

Is this correct? It's been a while since I took calculus and I had thought that intervals of continuity were relatively straightforward until this came up.

Comment: I don't think the word choice should matter.  $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 2$, so that point should be excluded.

Comment: @DMcMor That's what I thought at first, but a professor recently told me that, considering left/right continuity, sometimes it should be closed, but I'm still unsure why that is.

Comment: That's true, but I think that changes the question.  If you were told to find the intervals for which $f$ is *left-continuous* or *right-continuous* then the answer would change.

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you. This clears things up. I think there was an error in communication somewhere that I got too hung up on.